# Getting the count of markers in a layer in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I have a Leaflet map with a layer called flickrpics that is loaded dynamically in geojson based on the bbox of the current map view. I would like to get a simple count of the number of markers in that layer, so that I can display it next to the layer label in the layer control. I've tried things like flickrpics.length but it's saying undefined.

Apologies, pretty new to Leaflet and javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reference:**
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson

Methods inherited from LayerGroup:

getLayers() Layer[]

Returns an array of all the layers added to the group.

`var pins = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {}).addTo(map);
var totalPins = pins.getLayers().length;`

Answer (score 3):

If  you are using L.geoJson for geoJSON loading, you can use the onEachFeature to count the number of objects in the geoJSON layer. Something like:

```
var counter = 0;

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
counter++;
}

L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

See http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html for more information.

Comment: That's perfect, works a treat. I was looking for something already in the windows object that I could 'measure', but it makes perfect sense doing it this way, seeing as I already had an onEachFeature loop in there populating the pop-ups. Cheers (and apologies for the delay responding - I was on a plane)